# VMware Cluster > Host > VM datagrid view

Tags: powershell, datagrid, powercli

I am looking to create an easy powershell script which will get all clusters in a vcenter and for each one, get a list of hosts in that cluster, and then list all VMs in that cluster.  I can create the datagrid easy enough, though am unsure how to get it to change the row sizes.

Currently I have this but I don't know if it is actually working:

```
$Grid.Columns["Hosts"].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState]::True
```

Currently when I run it, I get the grid with my 3 columns (Cluster, Hosts, VMs).  However in the Hosts and VMs it displays System.Object[] instead of listing all hosts and VMs.

Lastly, would it be possible if say there are 5 hosts in the list, the row would grow to be 5 lines wide. If there are say 14 VMs in the same cluster, could I have it list VMs say 5, then 5, then 4 (so almost have columns in the row)?

Here is sorta what I have for the function to get the cluster, hosts, and VMs.  Perhaps my issue is in there as to why it shows System.Object:

```
Function Get-Info
{
$clusters = Get-Cluster

Foreach ($cluster in $clusters)
   {
    $hosts = get-cluster -name $cluster | get-vmhost | select Name
    $vms = get-cluster -name $cluster | get-vm | select Name 

$Grid.Rows.Add($cluster,$hosts,$vms)
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some digging after stepping away from it, I was able modify my code to the one below which will take multiple values and join them with a semi-colon.  This allowed me to dump them into an Excel sheet and then I could just do a Find/replace on the semi-colon to seperate out values.

In addition, I built an array to add in the values I want and pipe that into a CSV file.

```
$array = @()

$clusters = Get-Cluster

Foreach ($cluster in $clusters)
{

 $hosts = get-cluster -name $cluster | get-vmhost
 $gethosts =  ($hosts.Name | % { (get-vmhost $_).Name;}) -join ';';
 $vms = get-cluster -name $cluster | get-vm
 $getvms =  ($vms.Name | % { (get-vm $_).Name;}) -join ';';


    $obj = New-Object PSObject

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Cluster" -Value $cluster

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hosts" -Value $gethosts

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VMs" -Value $getvms

    $array += $obj
}


$array |  select Cluster, Hosts, VMs| export-csv "c:\temp\test\clusterinfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation -encoding ASCII -force
```